# Copy certain files to other folder using Python ( File Management in Python )

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check a folder and all subfolders if a certain file exists. If exists then I want to copy that in another folder. I have tried the following stuff

```
def copy_files(src, dest):
    files = os.listdir(src)
    for f in files:
        shutil.copy(src +f , dest)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(my_path):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".7z"):
            print("found files: " , f)
            copy_files(my_path, arch_dest)
```

On the copy_files function works. But it does not work inside the for the loop.

I am getting the following error:

> Permission denied: './data/f_1'

What am I doing wrong?

The Copy function works in other folders. But in this loop, it does not work. I need to make it work inside the loop.

### **Update:**

I am assuming the problem is more with the path, I have checked inside the for loop it shows the home directory where it is. with `print(os.getcwd())`

Do I need to then go to the folder while checking the file?

Comment: Did you get my question?  @Marcus.Aurelianus

Comment: Are you running this on Linux?

Comment: Windows 10, no not linux

Comment: Either run the script with sudo or from a shell that was started 'as administrator'?

Comment: If I apply the copy function in any other folder, it worked. In this for loop it does not work, how can I solve that? I am debugging in jupyter notebook

Comment: Does the function work when you put `./data/f_1` as the my_path parameter when called on it's own?

Comment: no, it says no such files. Although there is a file @jc1850

Comment: you'll need to use ".//data//f_1", to escape the backslashes, forgot about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution finally. I knew it in is because of the Root/Path. It has nothing to do with `admin/sudo` stuff.

It can be done as follows.

```
for r,d,files in os.walk(my_path):
    for f in files:
        print(r)
        shutil.copy(r + "/" + f, dest_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a try/except around the loop to ignore the files you dont have permission to search:

```
try:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(my_path):
        for f in files:
            if f.endswith(".7z"):
                print("found files: " , f)
                copy_files(my_path, arch_dest)
except OSError:
    pass
```

Comment: Is ./data/f_1 a destination or a file to be copied?

Comment: The files from the folder

Comment: The root folder has more directories. The code needs to check each folder and find the file

Comment: Does the traceback say anything else like which line is causing the error?

Comment: Thought it might not, so for some reason you dont have permission to do something to the file, do you know which line is causing the issue? Is it the `os.walk(my_path)` call?

Comment: Solved it check it out

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your `python` script as sudo user

```
e.g. sudo python filename.py
```

Comment: sudo does not exist in windows